# ¿Cómo invoco a una función asíncrona para recorrer la lista que me retorna, ya que quiero ponerla en mi ListTile?

Tags: python, flet

Mi idea es poder recorrer esa lista que retorna mi función asíncrona para que sean las opciones de mi Search Bar(ListTile) al final de mi código, sin embargo cuando lo hago me tira "Nonetype", como si no estuviese obteniendo su valor.

```
  class SearchBar(ft.UserControl):
        def __init__(self,data_received):
           self.data_received = data_received    
           super().__init__()

    def close_anchor(self,e):
        text = f"Color {e.control.data}"
        self.obj.close_view(text)
             
    async def data(self):
        db = Database(host="**", user="**", password="**", database="**")
        retorno = []
        query = "SELECT Patente, Tecnico FROM camionetas"
        results = await db.execute(query)
        for data in results:
            if self.data_received=="Patentes":
                retorno.append(data[0])
            elif self.data_received=="Tecnico":
                retorno.append(data[1])
    
        return (retorno)
    
    def create_search_bar(self):
        anchor = ft.SearchBar(
            value="",,
            divider_color=ft.colors.AMBER,
            
            controls=[

               ** ft.ListTile(title=ft.Text(f"{element}"), on_click=self.close_anchor, data=element)
                for element in self.data() **
                    
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

No tengo experiencia con Flet por lo que esta respuesta es fruto de un vistazo rápido a la documentación:

[Flet - Getting started with async](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/async-apps/#getting-started-with-async)

Parece que flet permite la creación de apps asíncronas con soporte nativo de *asyncio*, pero tienes realizar algunos cambios en la app, como hacer que la función de entrada `main` sea asíncrona y usar las versiones `_async` de los métodos correspondientes.

Por otro lado, el conector a tu base de datos debe soportar también `asyncio` para sacarle partido, o en el peor de los casos deberás envolver las llamadas al conector para que no bloqueen todo el ciclo de eventos.

En cuanto a como llamar a la función asíncrona para llenar el widget, generalmente lo que se suele hacer en estos casos es instanciar el widget vacío inicialmente y posteriormente ir generando el contenido conforme el código asíncrono retorne.

Te dejo un ejemplo reproducible basado en el código parcial que muestras usando sqlite3 como DB (y [*aiosqlite*](https://pypi.org/project/aiosqlite/) como driver asíncrono):

```
import aiosqlite
import flet as ft


# Solo para generar una base de datos sqlite3 para probar el codigo
async def create_test_database():
    async with aiosqlite.connect('test_database.db') as db:
        async with db.cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                await cursor .execute("""
                    CREATE TABLE camionetas (
                      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                      Patente TEXT, Tecnico TEXT
                    )""")
                rows = (('AAAAAA', "Pepe"), ('BBBBBB', 'Juan'),('CCCCCC', 'Ana'))
                await cursor.executemany("""
                    INSERT INTO camionetas (Patente, Tecnico) 
                    VALUES 
                      (?, ?)""", rows)
                await db.commit()
            except aiosqlite.OperationalError as e:
                pass


class SearchBar(ft.UserControl):
    def __init__(self, data_received):
       self.data_received = data_received
       self.anchor = None
       super().__init__()

    async def close_anchor(self, e):
        text = f"{e.control.data}"
        await self.anchor.close_view_async(text)
        
    async def load_data(self):
        query = f"SELECT {'Patente' if self.data_received=='Patentes' else 'Tecnico'} FROM camionetas"
        async with aiosqlite.connect('test_database.db') as db:
            async with db.execute(query) as cursor:
                async for element, *_ in cursor:
                    self.anchor.controls.append(
                         ft.ListTile(
                             title=ft.Text(f"{element}"),
                             on_click=self.close_anchor,
                             data=element)
                         )
        await self.update_async()

    def build(self):
        self.anchor = ft.SearchBar(
            value="",
            divider_color=ft.colors.AMBER,
        )
        return self.anchor


async def main(page):
   # Solo para generar una base de datos sqlite3 para probar el codigo 
    await create_test_database()
    
    search_bar = SearchBar(data_received="Tecnicos")
    await page.add_async(search_bar)
    await search_bar.load_data()
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ft.app(target=main)
```